# I want to make my bot "listening" to something

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make my discord bots status say listening to you. I have tried various metods I found. This is the only one that haven't made my bot stop working:

```
@client.event
    async def on_ready():
      client.user.setActivity('you', { type: 'LISTENING' });
```

With this my bot is still up, but it doesnt show a status. I also get this error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 9, in on_ready
    client.user.setActivity('to you', { type: 'LISTENING' });
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'setActivity'
```

Please ask I forgot to include something important.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-playing-status Read this bit of the docs. The issue is likely because of doing it in the on_ready

Answer (score 1):

Read the links:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.activity

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ActivityType

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Spotify.type

---

`setActivity` does not exist. `ActivityType.listening` only exists via `discord.Spotify`.

You change your activity with `change_presence`:

```
game = discord.Game("with the API")
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=game)

song = discord.Spotify(...)
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=song)
```

---

`setActivity` is from `discord.js`. You are however programming in Python and you are using `discord.py`.

Comment: I tried that, I get this error message in the example you put with game activity:

Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 9, in on_ready
    game = discord.Game("with the API")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'Game'

Comment: I hope you have not defined your bot variable as "discord", if you got change it and this should work